# Why this last condition else doesn't work properly C#

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have this (if-else if-else) statement it works fine except the else part I don't know why ?

```
void TakeAction()
{
    try
    {
        if (chkProduct.Checked == true && chkMaterial.Checked == false)
        {
            InsertProduct();
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Close();
        }

        else if (chkProduct.Checked == false && chkMaterial.Checked == true)
        {
            InsertMaterial();
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            this.Close();
        }

        else if (chkProduct.Checked == true && chkMaterial.Checked == true)
        {
            InsertSubProduct();
            MessageBox.Show("Done", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            this.Close();
        }

        // else if (chkProduct.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked && chkMaterial.CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked) // Tried this also still nothing
        else
        //Doesn't work
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check even one Checkbox", "Choose", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

I tried different ways like just else , else if And finally the commented line in code .
Thanks in advance.

Edit#1
I think this method interferes with the `TakeAction` method and causes the problem , I will debug my code from the start , Thanks

```
        if (chkProduct.Checked == true && chkMaterial.Checked == false)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [ProductCode] FROM Products Where [ProductCode] = @prcode ", Cn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", txtcode.Text);
            dt.Clear();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                //int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["ProductCode"].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicated", "Duplicated");

            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("No problem , Its not Product");
                TakeAction();
            }
        }

        //the first If >> If Material Or SubProduct
        else if (chkMaterial.Checked == true)
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code FROM Items Where Code = @prcode ", Cn);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", txtcode.Text);
            dt.Clear();

            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicated", "Duplicated");

            }
            else
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("No problem , Its not item");
                TakeAction();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesnt work? Is the else never been hit, or is an error being thrown executing the else statement.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is useless for us. Please provide details about how you expect it to work.

Comment: Does `TakeAction` get called if both are false (unchecked)? You probably need to debug your code to see what's happening

Comment: I would argue that the if-else construction in this case is unnecessarily complex construction. Try just doing an if for each of your instances... and if you do a return, then you can handle the case where it gets to the bottom just like that...  but yes.. a bit more detail would be good... and I suspect your logic to be the issue  :-)

Comment: Doesn't work means doesn't do anything at all not even an error message .

Comment: The logic of the idea is that I have two `CheckBox` need to check the possibilities of being checked or not , You will have 4 conditions you will find them in my code the problem is with the fourth when neither of them checked.Thanks

Comment: I think the problem with earlier method of mine maybe ,  Because i deleted all the else and left the if that checks if the both are not checked and it didn't work , I will debug my code from the start and comment with what i find . Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **4** different combinations in total:

```
chkProduct.Checked : chkMaterial.Checked : Action
--------------------------------------------------------------
              true :                true : InsertSubProduct()
              true :               false : InsertMaterial()
             false :                true : InsertProduct()
             false :               false : Ask User to Check
```

That's why you don't have to put the last condition as `else if`: `else` is enough. If you have problems with debugging you can change the code into *nesting* `if`s and push the last condition forward:

```
if (!chkProduct.Checked && !chkMaterial.Checked) 
  MessageBox.Show("Check even one Checkbox", 
                  "Choose", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                   MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
else {
  if (chkProduct.Checked)
    if (chkMaterial.Checked) 
      InsertSubProduct();
    else 
      InsertProduct();
  else 
    InsertMaterial();

  MessageBox.Show("Done", 
                  "Done", 
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                   MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , You got the logic right I tried your code still the same result as mine the message "Check even one Checkbox" doesn't show at all in your code or in mine.

Comment: The rest are working fine.

Comment: I think the both codes are fine but the problem with earlier method of mine maybe because i deleted all the else and left the first if that checks if the both are not checked and it didn't work , I will debug my code from the start and comment with what i find . Thanks all .

Answer (score 0):

If the else statement doesn't work it means that one of the else if statements is being hit. Have you tried breakpointing? You can also remove the true and false values to make it more readable.

Instead of:

```cs
if (x == true && y == false) { }
```

You can do the following:

```cs
if (x && !y) { }
```